# Can't build python gevent on mac osx 10.10

Tags: python, pip, gevent

Synopsis:
`pip install gevent` doesn't work.

Digging down, I downloaded the gevent `.tar.gz` and ran the build manually: `python setup.py build`, got the same error:

```
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'gevent.core' extension
clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -U__llvm__ -DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/libev -Ilibev -I/Users/travisjohnson/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/include/python2.7 -c gevent/gevent.core.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/gevent/gevent.core.o
In file included from gevent/gevent.core.c:313:
In file included from gevent/libev.h:2:
...
29 various compiler warnings
...
29 warnings generated.
clang -bundle -bundle_loader python.exe -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/travisjohnson/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib -U__llvm__ build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/gevent/gevent.core.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/gevent/core.so
ld: file not found: python.exe
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

My first thought is "It looks like it's telling clang to link `python.exe` into something", which initially I thought was nonsense (this isn't windows), but: https://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#unix says python.exe is the default name for python after building (because of case insensitivity), so now I don't know.

I've been digging at this for hours, and don't have a next step. [I found something similar (I think) on a different project](https://bitbucket.org/yt_analysis/yt/issue/868/install-script-installation-fails-on-os-x), but there was no explanation on the cause or what fixed it, just that it was fixed (I've checked that my xcode and developer tools etc are up to date)

I'm at a total loss for next steps here, could someone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**
Digging a bit more into running the build manually step by step, I did get *this* specific step to not error-out by:

- Finding the location of the `python` binary (not the shim used by pyenv)
- Manually running the `clang` command listed in the log, but replacing `python.exe` with the path to my `python` binary, ie: `/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/adid/bin/python2.7`

So it seems it isn't getting some correct path to the python binary? Unfortunately I don't know the remainder of the build process so I can't keep going on my own, and I don't know how to place this path correction into the process run by `setup.py`. I didn't have these issues before updating to 10.10 (could have been something else, it's been a few days and I've done other stuff), so I don't know why this is only a new issue.

Comment: have you tried doing `xcode-select --install` on this machine? errors related to `clang` are often caused by missing/improperly configured C++ compiler.

Comment: I have yes, I found similar recommendations elsewhere, was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: Must be something else blocking you, just installed on 10.10 - have you tried upgrading clang or gcc to a newer version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this is an issue with my virtualenv manager:

https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/273

`Unable to install compiled Python modules under pyenv on OS X 10.10` is the name of the issue.

**EDIT:**
No it isn't.

This is a bug with *python*. The way python did os version comparisons in OSX was naive, and broke with the double digit in 10.10, where it would then think you were on a much older OSX. This can often go unnoticed, except when installing compiled modules (where it's used to make some decisions).

This was fixed here: https://bugs.python.org/issue21811

I don't remember if 2.7.7 or 2.7.8 was the version with the released fix (but it was one of them), but the end result is you can't use older versions of 2.7 on OSX 10.10 or newer. If you're running into this issue then personally I'd push to upgrade the python version used ;) (2.7.11 has some awesome ssl improvements anyways).

Comment: For anyone struggling like me, the python version with the fix was 2.7.8. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You can fix the bug yourself, see https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/273#issuecomment-285038543