# modules compilation differences between 2.7.7 and 2.7.8

Tags: python, python-2.7, osx-yosemite

I've run into an issue with compiling (some) modules (specifically ones that use C extensions, ie: Cython) ever since I upgraded to Yosemite.

I asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259830/cant-build-python-gevent-on-mac-osx-10-10), and the end result was [this github issue](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/273) with the virtual environment manager I use. Since then however, the creator of said manger has [boiled down](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/273#issuecomment-67719984) the cause to some change in flags Python is passing to the C compiler.

I'll summarize the changes observed. In Python 2.7.7 and earlier, the following can be observed on OSX Yosemite:

```
python -c 'import sysconfig;print(sysconfig.get_config_var("BLDSHARED"))'
clang -bundle -bundle_loader python.exe -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/yyuu/.pyenv/versions/2.7.7/lib
```

On 2.7.8 and later, *this* can be observed:

```
python -c 'import sysconfig;print(sysconfig.get_config_var("BLDSHARED"))'
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/yyuu/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/lib
```

I've tested this independant of my virtualenv manager. The issue is pretty clear given the error message when I try to install a package with C extensions:

```
ld: file not found: python.exe
```

So now my question: I don't so much expect/want a 'fix', but an understanding of what caused this change. What does Python use to determine the output here? What is `BLDSHARED` derived from? If I understand this, then perhaps I can engineer a solution. I imagine it's something to do with how Python detects the environment it's building in.

Fixes are of course accepted as well, in lieu of better understanding :)